# Pass Variable - JAVA

Tags: java

I´m trying to use the variable `Var` (it coming from another Class) inside the `public void run()`. Inside the `public RandomWalk(double v2){ Var=v2; }`  I have the correct value.  Inside the `public void run()`   the value of `Var` is always 0. Any solution??

```
 public class RandomWalk implements Runnable
 {
public static double Var;

public RandomWalk(double v2){
  Var=v2;
}

public void run() {
    double p = currentTime / 1000.0 * 4;
    series0 = 20 + Math.cos(p * 2.2) * 10 + 1 / (Math.cos(p) * Math.cos(p) + 0.01);
    series1 = Var;
}
```

Thank you for your patience!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, is there any other code where `Var` is being edited or reset back to 0?

Comment: Why did you declare ``Var`` static? And: Are the constructor and the run method executed by differen threads?

Comment: How do you call the constructor? Is there any instance where you are calling `RandomWalk(0.0)`? Note that the field/variable is static which will mean all code will share the _same instance/field/_ (when ignoring classloaders which will be out of scope for now). - In essence we'd need a [mcve] because the code you posted is missing _a lot_.

Comment: Can you share your code as complete?

Comment: As Thomas said, how do you pass the variable? Did you call new RandomWalk(1.7)  in "the other class"?

Comment: How can I send the complete code? It´s too long to insert in comments....

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you set your `Var` only one time. Please remove public and add private to the property.

```
private static double Var;
```

Second check if you have some setter or modifier for this property (`Var`) inside your class `RandomWalk`. If there are such methods check if you need them and if so, check if they set the right value.

Now you are sure that the `Var` is set.

After that check the implementation of you method `run()`. Inside the method you should not have another `Var` declared. If you have then you do not use your **global** `Var`, but your **local** `Var` for the method.

And last check in this method `run()` if you do not set again your global `Var` somewhere before using it. Check for places like:

```
Var=something
```

Good luck!

Comment: A better approach would be to declare it ``private final double`` since static is not necessary and making it final makes it unmodifyable.

Comment: Yes this will be even better.